# sending multipart request using springboot rest client always give 400 BAD_REQUEST error

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

i have seen many examples on the internet on sending **multi-part** request from **Spring-Boot Rest Template** , but nothing actually worked for me i always end up getting a 400 bad request.i am not sure if the error is with the `FileSystemResource`  class that i use to store the file details in.

This is my Controller Class.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "multipart/form-data" },value = "/submit")
public ResponseEntity securedAcceptJob(
              @RequestParam(value = "files" , required = false)MultipartFile multipartFile,
              @RequestParam(value = "name" , required = true) String name
              ) throws NotInitializedException,CouldNotSendException {}


public void submitResponse(SrResultEntity srResultEntity){
    String path = "des/submit";
    LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object> requestEntity = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestEntity.add("name",srResultEntity.getTitle());
    requestEntity.add("files",getUserFileResource());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity(requestEntity, headers);

    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(buildPath(path)).buildAndExpand(pathVariables).toUri();

    final ResponseEntity<String> stringResponseEntity =
        restClientHelper.getRestTemplate().exchange(uri,HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
}

public static Resource getUserFileResource() throws IOException {
        //todo replace tempFile with a real file
        Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("upload-test-file", ".txt");
        Files.write(tempFile, "some test content...\nline1\nline2".getBytes());
        System.out.println("uploading: " + tempFile);
        File file = tempFile.toFile();
        //to upload in-memory bytes use ByteArrayResource instead
        return new FileSystemResource(file);
    }
```

i cant figure out the what should i change in the code , this is the output when i debug the application.

**<{name=[dwad], message=[null], email=[m@yhaoo.com], files=[file [/tmp/upload-test-file5318593104290391569.txt]]},{Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], X-Auth-Token=[6ce45ed4-3278-4531-98fa-fe5949000380], Content-Type=[multipart/form-data]}>**

the error still exist even if i dont send a file in the request.

stack trace :

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad
>   Request   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:698)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:619)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]     at
>   com.itesco.sam2.restclient.RestServiceClient.multiPartPost(RestServiceClient.java:52)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.itesco.sam2.restclient.des.DesServiceClient.submitResponse(DesServiceClient.java:131)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.itesco.sam2.ui.views.des.FileListView.sendReplies(FileListView.java:149)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.itesco.sam2.ui.views.AbstractEditorDialog.saveClicked(AbstractEditorDialog.java:202)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.itesco.sam2.ui.views.AbstractEditorDialog.lambda$open$cc13c671$1(AbstractEditorDialog.java:191)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:132)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:326)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$5ee67f2b$1(ComponentEventBus.java:190)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:378)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_171]  at
>   com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:378)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:58)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:63)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:377)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$0(ServerRpcHandler.java:367)
>   ~[flow-server-1.0.0.jar:na]   at
>   java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) ~[na:1.8.0_171]

Comment: can you post the stack trace as well?

Comment: I mean the completed stack trace. This exception can be generated from multiple reasons.

Comment: edited the question thanks.